# How to return TabFragment to FragmentActivity

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

hi im try to TabFragment to FragmentActivity. How Can i return google maps activity.
**TabFragment.java**

```
public class TabFragment extends Fragment {

public static TabLayout tabLayout;
public static ViewPager viewPager;
public static int int_items = 2;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /**
     *Inflate tab_layout and setup Views.
     */
    View x = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, null);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) x.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    /**
     *Set an Apater for the View Pager
     */
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));

    /**
     * Now , this is a workaround ,
     * The setupWithViewPager dose't works without the runnable .
     * Maybe a Support Library Bug .
     */

    tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }
    });

    return x;

}

class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    /**
     * Return fragment with respect to Position .
     */

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new PrimaryFragment();
            case 1:
                return new SocialFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return int_items;

    }

    /**
     * This method returns the title of the tab according to the position.
     */

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Primary";
            case 1:
                return "Social";

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**SocialFragment.java**

```
public class SocialFragment extends Fragment {


private TextView textView;

@Nullable
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, null);
}}
```

normally is correct. but im try to show google maps at SocialFragment.xml. maps show but functions is not working (for example Marker)

How can i change this line like this.

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new PrimaryFragment();
        case 1:
            return new MapsActivity();
    }
    return null;
}
```

when try this code error like this how can fix this problem.
[image]

Here is the xml files.

**activity_maps.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<fragment xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.ksk.kiblev2.MapsActivity"></fragment>
```

**MapsActivity.java**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private static final LatLng KibleKordinat = new LatLng(21.42247, 39.82619);
GoogleMap googleMap;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(27.700769, 85.300140);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Kathmandu, Nepal"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just transform the code of mapsactivity into some mapfragment and you'r set

Comment: what do you mean can you explain ?

Comment: See, Here you have an activity  @Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new PrimaryFragment();
        case 1:
            return new MapsActivity();
    }
    return null;
} Now put all your core functionalities of MapsActivity into Some Maps fragment and then return that fragment instead of that new MapsActivity()